# "Pure" VS "Purer" VS "More pure"

Tags: word-choice, spelling, comparative-degree

Q.1) What's the difference between ***pure***, ***purer***, and ***more pure***, and what's the correct situation to use each one?

Q.2) What should I write (pure, purer, or more pure) in the following blank?

> Juice contains many impurities, it must undergo purification in
> which a limestone filter is used to filter out the juice. Now, the
> juice is ______________.

Comment: What do _you_ understand as the difference between those words? A bit more information on your current knowledge would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Purer** and **more pure** are *comparatives.* Both are used, but not very often, because it could be argued that if something is pure (free of impurities), it can't be made any *more* pure.

Please note that a liquid is *filtered,* but the impurities are *filtered out.*

Answer (score 0):

For the majority of one-syllable adjectives, you just add -er to form the comparatives. As far as I know, the only exceptions are the irregular adjectives, for example good/better. Some two-syllable adjectives, for example gentle, are handled the same way.

For the majority of two syllable words, and all adjectives with three or more syllables, we use **more** followed by the adjective..

As this [Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more%20pure%2C%20purer&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmore%20pure%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpurer%3B%2Cc0) shows, **more pure** is used, but **purer** is much more common.